# Best way to pass props to child when parent is rendered in a map function

Tags: reactjs

My component structure is as follows: `Comp1 -> Comp2 -> Child`

In `Comp1` I'm mapping over an array of objects and rendering `Comp2` for each item in the array. But now I'm in a situation
where `Child` needs access to the `ID` field in the object.

In Comp1:

```
array.map((obj) => {
    return (
        <Comp2 />
    )
});
```

In Comp2 I have `<Child />`

I don't want to pass the object down from Comp1 to Child. What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Passing down a variable from Comp1 to Child is not bad practice, even if they arent directly Child-Parent. Its only when you need to Child to talk to Comp1 that you should be using a global state management library like Redux.

Comment: Is there any other pattern I could use, or perhaps even leverage Context api in this case? Just seems a bit annoying having to pass it down components that don't care about the value.

Comment: I agree with @ShawnAndrews that it's fine to pass through `Comp2`. Context would also work for what you're trying to do but personally I wouldn't. You could use rest/spread in `Comp2` to pass the prop through. Maybe that will feel less annoying...

```
const Comp2 = ({ propICareAbout, ...propsIDon'tCareAbout }) => <Child {...propsIDon'tCareAbout} />;
```

Comment: Yeah just send the Id from the object using destructing to the child instead of whole object.
`const {id} =obj
<child id={id}/>`